# Design ideas - Sharing contact across distributed system

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, distributed-system

The following is the architecture in our organizations.
We have a distributed system across multiple offices. Where each office works independently on their data (local data - unique id's in database). Sometimes these offices have to share data among themselves.
What is the best way of designing software(architecture) where data can be shared across multiple offices.

Scenario - Lets say an office 'A' is capturing data about a contact (Phillip with id- 258)
where the contact is tied to multiple organizations (located locally) and is involved in multiple events (local events) .

Lets say another office 'B' also is working on Phillips profile.

1. Whats the best way , where office A and B can share Phillips profile (without creating duplicates and not making it a central system).
2. Any changes to Phillip will show up in both of these systems (regarding organizations or local events he is related to from either of the office).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is to centralize the data base.  You could use the cloud, or pick one office that is the main and all other offices update the main.

Next up my choice would be some form of replication at the database level.  You would have to review the options provided by your database provider.

You could write a bunch of code, something like Restful services at each office and an update at one office would automatically send the change to the other offices.